# Open swal without clicking any ok or cancel icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using sweetalert 2 where I just need to open the swal directly calling ajax instead of doing an confirm or something, what change I need to do, following this code

```
https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/bootstrap.html
```

Tried it like this

```
$(document).on('click','.readmore',function() {
swal({
    title: 'ajax request pending',
    text: 'processing request',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    preConfirm => function(){
        url: 'https://example.com/controller/method/action',
        type: post,
        dataType: json,
        data: { key: value },
        success: swal.confirm( response.message ),
        error: swal.confirm( response.message )
    }
},
    function(){
        swal({
            title: 'ajax request finished',
            text: response.message,
            showSpinner: false,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: true
    });
    }
});
```

But it ended up in a error :d

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```